# How do you see which exceptions are thrown with Intellisense in VS2015?

Tags: c#, exception, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

**This was addressed and fixed in VS2015 Update 1**

---

Is there any way to show the Exceptions in VS2015?

VS2015

[image: ]([![https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzkPi.png]

VS2013

[image]

Comment: Your images doesn't have _any_ exception. They are methods, properties and fields etc..

Comment: Think this means exceptions that the methods can throw such as `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeExcpeption` as seen in the vs2013 image.

Comment: [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.close.aspx) doesn't have exceptions. So question is poor as it is now. Can you show the *same* method intellisense tooltip for both versions?

Comment: Your top screenshot is using C++ whilst the bottom one uses C#, have you tried using C# in 2015?

Comment: If you look at

VS2015 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx
VS2013 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b(v=vs.120).aspx

You can see how the "List Members" and "Parameter Info" changed. In VS2015 you no longer have the "Exceptions:" portion

Comment: I edited the top image to reflect the same method in VS2015

Comment: vote on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/9394263-show-exceptions-in-intellisense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS 2015 IntelliSense: Exceptions Thrown not Previewed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792546/vs-2015-intellisense-exceptions-thrown-not-previewed)

Comment: @burgi it is mine was first.

Comment: However, the one marked as a duplicate has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It no longer appears to show up in the intellisense tooltip until you actually write the code. Once the code is there hovering your mouse over it makes it appear in full.

Note: This appears to have only been fixed in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

[image]

Comment: Noticed that this was addressed in VS2015 Update 1

Comment: Yeah, I got update 1 a few days ago. Appears to have fixed the issue