# VS 2015 IntelliSense: Exceptions Thrown not Previewed

Tags: c#, xml, exception, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

I just upgraded to VS 2015 Enterprise Edition and am working with C#.

In VS 2013 I was able to add XML Exception tags to my methods and when trying to use that method I would see a preview of what Exceptions could be thrown.

However, in VS 2015 when I hover over my method call, or try to make the call I get no preview of what Exceptions can be thrown.

How can I make VS 2015 show what exceptions can be thrown by methods?

Below is my test class.

Thank you.

VS 2013

[image]

VS 2015

[image]

Comment: I also have this problem and it is very annoying

Comment: Are you using ReSharper?

Comment: No I am not using ReSharper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

You can download it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/11/30/visual-studio-update-1-rtm.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this kind of summary instead

```
    /// <summary>
    /// throws <exception cref="MyException">MyException</exception>
    /// </summary>
```

Comment: This syntax will work but it will require me to go through all of my exceptions and change them. I hoped that Microsoft would've preserved their previous functionality in VS 2013 and at least made it a toggled feature in the settings.

Comment: It looks like a parsing issue, so I am not sure that it is possible to configure it. Maybe that could change this behavior in some update or servicepack.