# Quick Info Not Displaying Possible Exceptions for Some Projects

Tags: c#, intellisense, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, quickinfo

I have always been able to hover over methods in my C# code and a list of possible exceptions is displayed in the quick info panel in Visual Studio 2015 Community - in fact this was working yesterday and this morning.

However, this afternoon after installing Visual Studio 2017 RC, I can no longer see this list of exceptions in 2 of my projects (in both VS2015 and VS2017).

My other projects seem to be okay, and I literally have no idea where to start with this. Do I need to check something in my project properties or the `.csproj` file itself?

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

I have installed all the updates for VS2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this exception list is not displayed for projecs which target the `.Net-3.5` framework and below (I **can** see the exception list when the project targets `.Net-3.5 Client Profile`)

This was confusing me because I originally copied the code from a `.Net-4.5` project which was displaying the exception list into a project which targets `.Net-3.5`, and I did not think that this would effect the documented exceptions.

When clicking on a method and pressing `F12` (or right-clicking and selecting `View Definition`), I can see the following:

#### .Net-3.5

```
public static void WriteLine(string value);
```

#### .Net-4.0

```
//
// Summary:
//     Writes the specified string value, followed by the current line terminator, to
//     the standard output stream.
//
// Parameters:
//   value:
//     The value to write.
//
// Exceptions:
//   T:System.IO.IOException:
//     An I/O error occurred.
public static void WriteLine(string value);
```

So it seems that the `XML` documentation for `.Net-3.5` just doesn't include these exception details.

I have not been able to find any other information on this, so not quite sure why the details are excluded when the same exceptions could be thrown regarldess of the framework version.

Answer (score 1):

This used to be a Problem with early VS2015 Versions and had been addressed in Vs2015 Update 1.

I suggest you trying to reinstall Update 1 for VS2015.

[VS 2015 IntelliSense: Exceptions Thrown not Previewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792546/vs-2015-intellisense-exceptions-thrown-not-previewed)

Comment: But why would this only be affecting a couple of my projects? Surely if the issue was with Update 1 then none of my projects would display the exception list. This also doesn't explain why VS2017RC is giving me the same issue

Comment: You surely got a point here..It was most likely a parsing issue in VS2015 which surely was dependant of serveral circumstances.

Comment: Do you know how I can reinstall update 1 on its own without having to reinstall all of VS?

Comment: Can you just install it over?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments Ian - I found the solution to the problem and created a new answer. Hopefully that will help someone else in the future!