# Missing Exception List In Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, intellisense

I am in the process of learning C# via Bob Tabor's "C# Fundamentals for Absolute Beginners" course on [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners). I am about halfway through the lesson on exceptions.

Bob mentions that when hovering over a method the IntelliSense window that pops up lists the potential exceptions that the method could have. However in my version of Visual Studio (Community Edition 2015) the IntelliSense window is much slimmer and does not contain the list of potential exceptions.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rexol.png]
Screenshot of the missing IntelliSense text.

Have I missed an option I need to turn on or has this ability been removed for the new version of Visual Studio?

If it has been removed what are the 3rd party options to reintroduce this feature?

Thanks

Comment: It appears as if the intelliSense in VS2015 is changed (they didn't just add colors to it). I just tried it with a StreamReader in VS 2013 and it lists the exceptions for me, but in 2015 it does not.

Comment: You might need to install the full documentation

Comment: Exactly the same question was posted here. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c411a63d-952f-4406-8327-30b33946192c/intellisense-not-showing-exceptions-list-in-vs-community-2015?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: This has been asked twice before on SO with no resolution, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792546/vs-2015-intellisense-exceptions-thrown-not-previewed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590390/how-do-you-see-which-exceptions-are-thrown-with-intellisense-in-vs2015) so I don't think there is a way to do it. This feedback ticket is mentioned in one of the other questions http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/9394263-show-exceptions-in-intellisense

Comment: @Dennis_E I must have missed that one when I originally did my googling of the problem.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for that if you add your comment as an answer I'll accept that as the "solution"

Comment: @Burgi, okay, done. I also voted on the UserVoice ticket as well. I haven't started using 2015 yet, but this is a feature I'd like to see put back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been asked twice before on SO with no resolution ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792546/vs-2015-intellisense-exceptions-thrown-not-previewed), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590390/how-do-you-see-which-exceptions-are-thrown-with-intellisense-in-vs2015)) so it is unlikely that it currently possible to enable this.

There is an existing [UserVoice ticket](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/9394263-show-exceptions-in-intellisense) to bring it back though.

Comment: I have accepted this as the solution as it appears to have been removed from VS2015 and provides a link to the feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c411a63d-952f-4406-8327-30b33946192c/intellisense-not-showing-exceptions-list-in-vs-community-2015?forum=visualstudiogeneral) gives a partial answer to your question.

**"If you want to know the exception information, please select the class, right click, go to Definition, and you will see the detailed exception information"**

According to @Brandon comment I think this is only way to see exception list

Comment: Yes takes me 10 seconds to browse, click on the member (plus sign) to see the exception. You're wag